# Python: change the first element to the list itself

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]
```

And I want to change the first element to the list, so a list inside a list.
My first try:

```
mylist + mylist[1:]
```

gives me

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3] # not what I want
```

my second try

```
mylist[0]=mylist
```

gives me

```
[[...], 2, 3] # is this an infinite list?
```

Although I want

```
[[1,2,3], 2, 3]
```

Comment: _"is this an infinite list?"_ - Yes, it contains itself.

Comment: But is it the same as the desired output?

Comment: No, that `...` expands to `[[[[...], 2, 3], 2, 3], 2, 3]` (and on forever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mylist[0] = mylist` is pointing to reference of the mylist.  You can visualise it something like  this [image]

Every 1st element is having  a list which is again having another list. And  this  continues.

So the  solution to   your problem is  something like  this

```
>>> mylist = [1,2,3]
>>> mylist[0] = mylist[:]
>>> mylist
[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

`mylist[0] = mylist` gives you a list that contains itself - meaning `mylist == mylist[0] == mylist[0][0] == mylist[0][0][0] == ...`. It sounds like that's not what you want.

From the output you give, you problem is better stated as either:

- Making a new list that contains the old one - `mylist = [mylist] + mylist[1:]`
- Putting *a copy of* the list into itself - <s>`mylist[0] = mylist[:]`</s> `mylist[0] = mylist.copy()`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
temp = mylist
mylist[0] = temp[:]
```

Answer (score 2):

The second attempt kind-of has the right idea, but as you noted, it will cause an infinite recursion when printing it, since the list contains itself. By the expected output, it looks like you want to clone the list, which can be done pretty elegantly with slices:

```
mylist[0] = mylist[:]
```

Comment: Can we please stop using `[:]` to copy lists and use the hundred times more readable `mylist.copy()`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: I had no idea that existed. As a nice bonus, `.copy()` behaves identically for `ndarray`s and `list`s, unlike `[:]` which has different semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
mylist = [1,2,3]

mylist[0] = list(mylist)
print(mylist)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], 2, 3]
```